Does shudras should do anga nyasa and kara nyasa?
Many shudras take Ishta devata mantras as Diksha.
Shastras as prescribed anga nyasa and kara nyasa for mantra.
According to dharma Sidhu and brihaddharma purāṇa ,
Shudras should not recite Om, Swaha, Vashat, Vaushat .. etc.
shudras should do nyasa or not ? Whether shudra any other type of nyasa what is that nyasa and where it is told ?

Kalikapurana states an alternative of Pranava for sudras, & the others can be substituted with namah. See Sudrakriryavicaranatattva of Raghunandana & Sudradharmatattvaprakasa of Kamalakara Bhatta.

Does Hindi translation is available

No. Raghunandana's work has only the Sanskrit original while Kamalakara Bhatta's work has both the Sanskrit original & Marathi translation.

I can read Telugu,English,Hindi

I request is by quoting that shastras can you answer by question clearly
